# how to perform all grayscale image operation on rgb image?

Tags: image-processing

I know ,how to perform Operation like brightness,contrast etc on grayscale image.
I want to know how to perform all this operation on RGB color image?

Comment: Split the channels and do the operations seperately. You need to be more specific about the question, e.g. in which platform you want to do the operation? If you have done an operation on a grayscale image and you want to apply it to a color image, you should share your code and state what you have tried so far.

Comment: There is no common solution for all algorithms. For brightness and contrast, you can scale all RGB elements by the same scale factor, and add same offset to all. For histogram equalization (for example), you can convert RGB to HSV (or to LAB), apply EQ on the brightness channel V (or L) and convert back to RGB.